# Why is searching not returning results in Magento 1.9 with error messages appearing in nginx logs for FastCGI and Elastica?

Tags: php, nginx, magento-1.9

I'm running Magento 1.9.4 on Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.2 with nginx 1.14 fronting it all. The shopping site is loading and navigable. However, when I search for a term, it does not list the matches in the drop-down and shows the no results page.

I can see the following message in the nginx error logs:

```
2020/05/22 14:54:51 [error] 1213#1213: *270 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/example.com/lib/Elastica/Status.php on line 69
PHP message: PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/example.com/lib/Elastica/Status.php on line 81
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: version in /var/www/example.com/lib/Elastica/Client.php on line 108" while reading response header from upstream, client: 72.71.71.72, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /catalogsearch/result/?q=trouser HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/boutique/"
```

This was working prior to upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 7.0.

Comment: You are probably going to have to put some debug code into `/var/www/example.com/lib/Elastica/Status.php` to find who is calling that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to find another job.

Magento is using Elastica client which in turn is pointing to AWS ElasticSearch service. I had to whitelist the host (Magento site) in the AWS ElasticSearch access policy in order for it to access the service.